# How to change commerce order owner to someone else?

Tags: commerce

I create a commerce order for a spesific user prograticaly by admin user, after completing checkout process by admin, I want to change owner of order to someone else to show created order in order history of spesific user
I changed the uid of order but does not work for me.

Comment: In D7 or D8 commerce?

Comment: tnx, in D7 commerce

Answer (score 1):

-> If you want to do programatically, then Load Order as
$order = commerce_order_load(1);
$order->uid = 4;
commerce_order_save($order);

-> By admin UI
   Edit order and in User Information, specofy username of user you want to assign and save.
[image]